Multi-Select FileField is not returning list of files based in the order I selected them
I am trying to upload multiple images at once using the filefield xtype but when I get the list of selected files, the list is not in the order I selected them in. It looks to be automatically sorting them based on some other criteria. Is there a way to get list of file names based on the order I selected them?
xtype: 'filefield',
id: 'figureFileUpload',
buttonText: 'Browse Files From Device',
handler: 'onBrowseFiles',
buttonOnly: true,
multiple: true,
height: 45,
listeners: {
    change: 'figureFilefieldChange',
    render: function (me, eOpts) {
        var el = document.getElementById(me.id+'-button-fileInputEl');
        if(me.multiple) {
            el.multiple = true;
        }
    }
}


automatically sorting them based on some other criteria looks like increasing file size - at least in firefox

create your own storage variable ( object literal or a Map perhaps ) and populate that when a new file is selected

When looking at the Extjs event for a file field there isn’t an event avail that triggers when a file is clicked inside the file browser.

How do you select multiple files? One after another or all at the same time? If you select all at the same time, how do you want them to be sorted in the order you picked them? And its always good to let us know that you are in classic and not in modern. Helps a lot

To clarify I want to select the multiple files all at the same time and I want the files sort in the order I picked them. I think I am using modern but I will have to clarify when I get back in the office. Thanks!

You have to grab the files and store them yourself.
Here is an example:
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    fullscreen: true,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        xtype: 'fieldset',
        title: 'My Uploader',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'filefield',

            /**
             * @cfg {String[]} fileArray
             * Array to store your files in order of choosing
             */
            fileArray: [],
            
            buttonText: 'Browse Files From Device',
            buttonOnly: true,
            multiple: true,
            
            listeners: {
                change: function (fileField) {
                    // => store the new file
                    fileField.fileArray.push(fileField.getValue());

                    // for Demo only
                    Ext.Array.each(
                        fileField.fileArray,
                        function(filePath) {
                            console.log(filePath)
                        }
                    );
                }
            }
        }]
    }]
});

If you are looking for the multiple functionality, here is a working fiddle:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3rtk

Is there any way to get this to work with control clicking multiple files from the file browser? I added the ability to control click multiple files in my code snippet.

I added a working fiddle. It allows to selecte multiple files via CRTL or SHIFT key. If your question is, if you can keep track of the order in a single run, my answer is no. I did not manage to do so without ExtJS, with a pure html construct and it did not give me the order either.
